# Inherited module error after adding GXT? - NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/Generator?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gxt

I am using GWT 2.5

GXT 2.5.1

App Engine 1.9.0

I am getting this error.

```
Loading modules
   com.java.operastar.Opera_Star
      Loading inherited module 'com.java.operastar.Opera_Star'
         Loading inherited module 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'
            [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/Generator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$ClassAttrCvt.convertToArg(ModuleDefSchema.java:884)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerArgs.convertToArg(HandlerArgs.java:64)
.
.
.
.
```

Can anybody help to solve this.
[image: Screen short]

Comment: Please again have a look at [Setting Up Your First Ext GWT Project in Eclipse](http://www.sencha.com/blog/setting-up-your-first-ext-gwt-project-in-eclipse).

Comment: Find your solution at [GWT 1.64 Class not found exception GXT module declaration is.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131950-Loading-inherited-module-com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT-**-com-google-gwt-core-ext-Generator) where the same problem is solved.

Comment: Is `gwt-dev.jar` added in project's class-path?

Comment: Its working fine for me. I am using `GWT 2.5.0` and `gxt.2.2.1`.

Comment: OR you can try with `<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />` instead of `<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />`

Comment: Please check your GXT version. [Announcing Sencha GXT 3.1 Beta](http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-gxt-3.1-beta)

Comment: Most probably its a version issue between GWT and GXT.

Comment: it was working fine for me previously for other projects.
Yes there is gwt-dev.jar in class path. '<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />' doent work.

Comment: What changes have you made now?

Comment: Have you confirmed the GXT version?

Comment: I didnt do any changes, i just created new project

Comment: Please validate what I have suggested in my post. Check the jars present in classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the issue is due to version mismatch between `GWT` and `GXT`.

Try any one option:

- try with `GWT 2.5.0` and `GXT.2.2.1` as shown in screenshot

[image]

- use below inherits in `gwt.xml` as shown in screenshot also

  ```
  <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  <inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
  ```

[image]

---

--EDIT--

Whenever you change the dependencies or GWT version. Just delete the last auto-generated stub as shown in below screenshot and re-compile the project again. A fresh start.

[image]

Comment: the combination of  'GWT 2.5.0' and 'GXT 2.2.1' works . But still i see some errors in Console

`Infos: Dev App Server is now running
[ERROR] Failure in unit cache map load.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Have a look at my edited post. Just delete the `gwt-unitCache` and other auto-generated stub after changing the GWT version and re-compile the project again.

Comment: Can you help me with this..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326527/unable-to-load-module-entry-point-in-gwt-gxt-project